# On what does the time complexity for graph algorithms depends on?

Tags: time-complexity, dijkstra, prims-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I stumbled over this question in my textbook:

> "In general, on what does the time complexity of Prim's, Kruskal's and Dijkstra's algorithms depends on?"
>
> a. The number of vertices in the graph.
> b. The number of edges in the graph.
> c. Both, on the number of vertices and edges in the graph.
>
> Explain your choice.

So according to Wikipedia Prim's,Kruskal's and Dijkstra's algorithms worst case time complexities are `O(ElogV)`, `O(ElogV)` and `O(E+VlogV)` respectively. So i guess the answer is c? But why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Prim's and Kruskal's and might be wrong about Dijkstra's but I think in its case the answer would be b because:

Dijkstra's will visit nodes on the shortest known path until it finds the destination.

This implies that if two edges point to the same node, only one will ever be considered by the algorithm since one has a higher weight or they're equal, rendering one edge moot to follow.

Therefore, the only way to increase the time spent traversing the graph by adding edges is by adding nodes (adding edges on existing node can change the algorithm's traversal time but it's **not proportional to the amount of edges, only to their weights**).

Therefore, my intuition is that only the amount of nodes are in direct relation with running time.  The [Dijkstra's Alogrithm wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time) seems to confirm this:

> The simplest implementation of the Dijkstra's algorithm stores
>   vertices of set Q in an ordinary linked list or array, and extract
>   minimum from Q is simply a linear search through all vertices in Q. In
>   this case, the running time is O(E + V^2) or **O(V^2)**.

This is only an intuition of course, and [cs.stackex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be of greater use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (c), because both V and E contribute to the asymptotic complexity of the respective algorithms. Now, on further analysis one could argue that V is much less on Kruskal's and Prim's(since it is log factor). But E seems to almost have same weights in all three cases.

Also, note that |E| <= |V|^2 always (for simple graphs)

Answer (score 0):

In worst case graph will be a complete graph i.e v(v-1)/2 edges ie e>>v and e ~ v^2

Time Complexity of Prim's and Dijkstra's algorithms are:
1. With Adjacency List and Priority queue:
    O((v+e) log v) in  worst case: e>>v so O( e log v)
2. With matrix and Priority queue:
      O(v^2 + e log v) in WC e ~ v^2
    So  O(v^2 + e log v) ~ O(e + e log v) ~ O(e log v).
3. When graph go denser ( Worst case is Complete Graph ) we use Fibonacci Heap 
    and adjacency list:    O( e + v log v)

Time complexity of kruskal is O(e log e) in Worst case e ~ v^2
so log (v^2) = 2 log v

So we can safely say than  O(e log e) can be O( 2e log v) 
ie O( e log v) in worst case.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the time complexities of O(ElogV), O(ElogV), and O(E+VlogV) mean that each one is dependent on both E and V.  This is because each algorithm involves considering the edges and their respective weights in a graph.  Since for Prim’s and Kruskal’s the MST has to be connected and include all vertices, and for Dijkstra’s the shortest path has to pass from one vertex to another through other intermediary vertices, the vertices also have to be considered in each algorithm.

For example, with Dijkstra’s algorithm, you are essentially looking to add edges that are both low in cost and that connect vertices that will eventually provide a path from the starting vertex to the ending vertex.  To find the shortest path, you cannot solely look for a path that connects the start vertex to the end, and you cannot solely look for the smallest weighted edges, you need to consider both.  Since you are considering both edges and vertices, the time it takes to make these considerations throughout the algorithm will depend on the number of edges and number of vertices.

Additionally, different time complexities are possible through different implementations of the three algorithms, and analyzing each algorithm requires a consideration of both E and V.

For example, Prim’s algorithm is O(V^2), but can be improved with the use of a min heap-based priority queue to achieve the complexity you found: O(ElogV).  O(ElogV) may seem like the faster algorithm, but that’s not always the case.  E can be as large as V^2, so in dense graphs with close to V^2 edges, O(ElogV) becomes O(V^2). If V is very small then there is not much difference between O(V^2) and O(ElogV).  E and V also influence the running time based on the way that the graph is being stored.  For example, an adjacency list becomes very inefficient with dense graphs (with E approaching V^2) because checking to see if an edge exists in the graph goes from close to O(1) to O(V).